# Entering paypal credentials in Braintree Control panel

Tags: paypal, sandbox, braintree

My Braintree Control Panel in sandbox does not show option to enter my  PayPal credentials.It just displays Accept PayPal (USA Only). Whats wrong with that?

Comment: The Braintree Sandbox uses a simulated PayPal integration. This is similar to how it simulates a credit card processing merchant account. When you move on to setting up a production account with PayPal it will then prompt you for credentials for your PayPal Business Account. (Disclosure, I work for Braintree)

Comment: @john.. I was also wondering I may get that 'paypal setting interface' when I switch to production mode. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: I faced the same problem. It seems that there is no way to test paypal payments using braintree sandbox, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use this feature you will need to either sign up for a free PayPal Business Account or verify your PayPal Business Account.

Check out here for more information: https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/1593802-paypal-setup-guide#biz

Once you verify your PayPal Business Account you should be able to enter your PayPal credentials in the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

No, seems its not possible.

When you click the sandboxed `PayPal` button, Braintree has already created and used a fake user and the only options you have is to either `Proceed with Sandbox Purchase` or `Cancel Sandbox Purchase`. If you click the `Proceed ...` button the details of the user you get back are `John Doe`, `Chicago` etc (at least these results are for my sandbox).

**Extra**: If you want to know these values then `console.log` the data returned when you click on the `Proceed with Sandbox Purchase` button, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
braintree.setup("CLIENT_TOKEN", "custom", {
                paypal: {
                    container: 'paypal-container',
                },
                onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
                    console.log(obj);
                }
            });
</script>
```

Hope this helps you!